# Why doesn’t “ssh user@machine1” require passphrase, but “ssh root@machine2” does?

Tags: ssh, security

This is from a DigitalOcean login issue that I researched [after reading this question on the official DigitalOcean support site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/permission-denied-after-creating-droplet-using-ssh-keys). I was getting rejections with my initial:

```
ssh root@$IP_DO
```

From the above link, I first narrowed it down to:

```
ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly yes" -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@$IP_DO
```

When I did the above it asked for a passphrase.  I opened my password manager, and sure, enough I had set a passphrase on that key.  Enter it and I am in.

(If it matters, I entered the public key when I set up my Digital Ocean account and just picked it for my droplet creation).

A bit of `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, entered the passphrase once, and now I am not being asked for a password anymore by DigitalOcean.

But, even before I did that ssh-add above, I could always ssh into Virtualbox VMs on a server on my LAN, no problem.  These are bitnami VMs, btw.

In both cases, DigitalO cean and VM, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` show the same thing:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC35MyHYQPWgHgxOffs2oI4jAJCTSldYr1tMb/LMogbTXtQW35mSsWexiwYjPIcdkkOl2Zqrt43696U1oZco90ibkFrbbXrqDGZssbaqfqk7
…
```

And looking at **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

#### DigitalOcean:

```
egrep 'Authentication|PAM|Pass' /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v '^#
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM yes

uname -rv
4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017
```

#### Bitnami VM

```
egrep 'Authentication|PAM|Pass' /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v '^#'
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes

uname -rv
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26)
```

Now, reading further on that thread, it advised to run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.  That asked for the key's passphrase.

Now, both DigitalOcean and the VM work without passphrase, but I am curious why the VM never needed the passphrase and DigitalOcean did?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've solved and I am pretty sure I know what happened.

SSL will try remote public_keys stored  in **authorized_keys** vs local keys using a challenge system.  You don't really know, or control, the sequence of what it tries out.

machine1 (VM) root's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` pointed to one of my keys that was not passphrase protected, say **github**.  It also had **id_rsa**, but never got to asking about it because it got in before **id_rsa**, using **github**.

machine2 (Digitalocean) root's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` did not include a reference to my unprotected **github** identity key, so it eventually got to **id_rsa**.  Since that **id_rsa**'s identity had not been loaded into the ssh-agent and since it is passphrase-protected, I was asked for the passphrase.

Note that this contradicts my statement that authorized keys were the same.  id_rsa's entry was, in both files, but there were other public keys on the Bitnami VM.

Comment: as a passing comment.  SSH is quite powerful and actually pretty simple.  But the basics take a bit of practice to understand.  Well worth using to get away from passwords and logins, but you need to invest some time to understand how the magic happens.